# Add string between tabs and text

Tags: python, regex

I simply want to add string after (0 or more) tabs in the beginning of a string.
i.e.

```
a = '\t\t\tHere is the next part of string.  More garbage.'
```

(insert `Added String here.`)
to

```
b = '\t\t\t Added String here. Here is the next part of string.  More garbage.'
```

What is the easiest/simplest way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
re.sub(r'^(\t*)', r'\1 Added String here. ', inputtext)
```

The `^` caret matches the start of the string, `\t` a tab character, of which there should be zero or more (`*`). The parenthesis capture the matched tabs for use in the replacement string, where `\1` inserts them again in front of the string you need adding.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '\t\t\tHere is the next part of string.  More garbage.'
>>> re.sub(r'^(\t*)', r'\1 Added String here. ', a)
'\t\t\t Added String here. Here is the next part of string.  More garbage.'
>>> re.sub(r'^(\t*)', r'\1 Added String here. ', 'No leading tabs.')
' Added String here. No leading tabs.'
```

Comment: @iCodez: I misread; I thought this required *one* or more tabs. Corrected.

Comment: Ahh. I was looking into `re.sub` but wasn't sure of `\1` use. Thanks! :)